# No such external account on stripe when trying to payout to bank_account

Tags: curl, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make a payout using stripe, So the first thing i did is to check my available balance using

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance
-u sk_test_MkyVP8GpUk______:
```

it returns this:

```
{
  "object": "balance",
  "available": [
    {
      "currency": "usd",
      "amount": 6004,
      "source_types": {
      "card": 52,
      "bank_account": 5952
    }  
 }
],
  "connect_reserved": [
    {
      "currency": "usd",
      "amount": 0
    }
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "pending": [
    {
      "currency": "usd",
      "amount": 6351,
      "source_types": {
      "card": 12303,
      "bank_account": -5952
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

All i understand from this response is that `avaiable[card] = 52` it means that if i want to make a payout to a credit card it should be a sufficient amount of money on it, Now there is $59,52 in `avaiable[bank_account]`, So i decided to make a payout to an external account of an account on stripe, using their API docs i used this:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payouts \
-u sk_test_MkyVP8GpUkur______: \
-d amount=400 \
-d currency=usd \
-d destination=ba_1B3jVULjo5______ \
-H "Stripe-Account: acct_1B0T___"
```

This destination (ba_1B3jVULjo5____) is an external account of that account ID, the problems is when i process this `curl` it gives me:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account for this transfer. Your card balance is too low.  You can use the the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance).",
    "param": "destination"
  }
}
```

How can i fix this?, is my understanding to the `type_source` in `avaiable` balance is correctly?

I make sure that there is an external account to the account with that id too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try including the [`source_type`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_payout-source_type) parameter in your [payout creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_payout):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payouts \
  -u sk_test_...: \
  -H "Stripe-Account: acct_..." \
  -d amount=400 \
  -d currency=usd \
  -d destination=ba_... \
  -d source_type=bank_account
```

Note that you can omit the [`destination`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_payout-destination) parameter entirely unless there are multiple bank accounts for the currency and you want to send the funds to a non-default bank account.

Comment: It worked thank you very much, When i run `balance` api without putting the `Stripe-Account` in the header, the returned response belongs to whom? like the one above.

Comment: Another question, Is putting `destination` when i request for a charge makes stripe move money to the balance of the destination until a payout it to an external account?

Comment: @AmrAdel If you don't include the `Stripe-Account` header, the request will be executed on the account to which the API key belongs. In this case, I assume it'd be your platform's account. And yes, when you create a charge with the `destination[account]` parameter, the funds are added to the connected account's balance.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ywain, You saved my time.

Comment: how to get destination bank account id programatically please explain or could you share any links stripe payouts @Thanks

Comment: @Ywain
I added source_type and I got another error. 
No such external account: 'ba_1Mo5AB4ZPY971ZQu2hiFHKti'
Can you help me?